# What's wrong with Bing bot Index?

Tags: url, search-engine-indexing, bing, bing-webmaster-tools, bingbot

I'm facing serious issues with Bing since last year. To start, most organic traffic of my website came from Bing when compared to others search engines. I wouldn't make a fuss if the situation was different. My site was kicked out of index because of duplicate meta tags, which I had hard time to find out. I found the cause much later, this year. It was due to internal bug.

I contacted them so many times, while I was trying to know **why** they did such thing. Alright, in two times they gave themselves a work to investigate the issue manually instead of using their useless automated system and confirmed whatever Bing bot accused my website was true, but refused to elaborate further, what I think would've helped me solve the issue faster, and maybe I would see my website in search results now...

[image: Bing URL Inspector Index Result]

[image: Bing URL Inspector Live Test]

That time I was beginner and I didn't know how to properly use URL Inspection like now to troubleshoot SEO related issues... They said if I solved the issue it would take one to two months to Bing Index my website again and recommended to use URL Submission or IndexNow Protocol to speed up the process. Practically for more than a month I've been wasting my time submitting the root URL and few others many times a day, but I don't see any slight, I mean at least a little change. I tried to make Bing clear the older Index cache too... But Bing won't update Index.

I also used to run many site scans (over 1000 pages per scan, my quota was 1000), that confirmed that duplicates issue was fixed, and in hope Bing bot would index my site more faster. For more than 21 days (nearly a month) they won't replenish my quota and strangely my URL submission quota was reduced from 100 to 10! As if the situation wasn't annoying enough, all new URLs are also falsely flagged!

**Bing Site Scan**
[image: Bing Site Scan List]

**Bing Site Scan Quota that won't replenish**
[image: Bing Site Scan Quota]

**Bing Reduced URL Submission Quota**
[image: Bing Daily URL Submission Quota]

Comment: You can double-check your site for duplicates with Screaming Frog SEO Spider. https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/ It will scan your site for you and let you know what is going on with it. It would be a good place to start to make sure something else hasn't gone off the rails. And the free version is fine for sites up to 500 pages.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the recommendation. I already fixed the duplicates more than a month ago, and I confirmed that I don't have duplicates anymore in any URL of the website since then.